# Curl login error on RESTful-ish API

Tags: php, curl, authentication

I am using the following code  to login to asp website but it doesnt work.

```
<?php
/************************************************
* ASP.NET web site scraping script;
* Developed by MishaInTheCloud.com
* Copyright 2009 MishaInTheCloud.com. All rights reserved.
* The use of this script is governed by the CodeProject Open License
* See the following link for full details on use and restrictions.
*   http://www.codeproject.com/info/cpol10.aspx
*
* The above copyright notice must be included in any reproductions of
this script.
************************************************/
error_reporting(E_ALL);
/************************************************
* values used throughout the script
************************************************/
// urls to call - the login page and the secured page
$urlLogin = "http://www.website.com/Default.aspx";
$urlSecuredPage = "http://www.website.com/Default.aspx";

// POST names and values to support login
$nameUsername=rawurlencode('ctl00$txtLoginName');       // the name of the username textbox on the login form
$namePassword=rawurlencode('ctl00$txtPassword');       // the name of the password textbox on the login form
$nameLoginBtn=rawurlencode('ctl00$btnLogin');          // the name of the login button (submit) on the login form
$valUsername ='myusername';        // the value to submit for the username
$valPassword ='mypass';        // the value to submit for the password
$valLoginBtn ='Login';             // the text value of the login button itself

// the path to a file we can read/write; this will
// store cookies we need for accessing secured pages
$cookieFile = 'cookie.txt';

// regular expressions to parse out the special ASP.NET
// values for __VIEWSTATE and __EVENTVALIDATION
$regexViewstate = '/__VIEWSTATE\" value=\"(.*)\"/i';
$regexEventVal  = '/__EVENTVALIDATION\" value=\"(.*)\"/i';


/************************************************
* utility function: regexExtract
*    use the given regular expression to extract
*    a value from the given text;  $regs will
*    be set to an array of all group values
*    (assuming a match) and the nthValue item
*    from the array is returned as a string
************************************************/
function regexExtract($text, $regex, $regs, $nthValue)
{

if (preg_match($regex, $text, $regs)) {
 $result = $regs[$nthValue];
}
else {
 $result = "";
}
return $result;
}



/************************************************
* initialize a curl handle; we'll use this
*   handle throughout the script
************************************************/
$ch = curl_init();


/************************************************
* first, issue a GET call to the ASP.NET login
*   page.  This is necessary to retrieve the
*   __VIEWSTATE and __EVENTVALIDATION values
*   that the server issues
************************************************/
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlLogin);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0' );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
$data=curl_exec($ch);
echo curl_error($ch);
// from the returned html, parse out the __VIEWSTATE and
// __EVENTVALIDATION values
$viewstate = regexExtract($data,$regexViewstate,$regs,1);
$eventval = regexExtract($data,$regexEventVal,$regs,1);
/************************************************
* now issue a second call to the Login page;
*   this time, it will be a POST; we'll send back
*   as post data the __VIEWSTATE and __EVENTVALIDATION
*   values the server previously sent us, as well as the
*   username/password.  We'll also set up a cookie
*   jar to retrieve the authentication cookie that
*   the server will generate and send us upon login.
************************************************/
$postData = '__VIEWSTATE='.rawurlencode($viewstate)
          .'&__EVENTVALIDATION='.rawurlencode($eventval)
          .'&'.$nameUsername.'='.$valUsername
          .'&'.$namePassword.'='.$valPassword
          .'&'.$nameLoginBtn.'='.$valLoginBtn
          ;

curl_setOpt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlLogin);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFile);    

$data = curl_exec($ch);


/************************************************
* with the authentication cookie in the jar,
* we'll now issue a GET to the secured page;
* we set curl's COOKIEFILE option to the same
* file we used for the jar before to ensure the
* authentication cookie is sent back to the
* server
************************************************/
curl_setOpt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlSecuredPage);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieFile);    

$data = curl_exec($ch);

// at this point the secured page may be parsed for
// values, or additional POSTS made to submit parameters
// and retrieve data.  For this sample, we'll just
// echo the results.
echo $data;


/************************************************
* that's it! Close the curl handle
************************************************/
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

HTML CODE of the website:

```
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__LASTFOCUS" id="__LASTFOCUS" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKMTIblablabla" />
</div>
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__PREVIOUSPAGE" id="__PREVIOUSPAGE" value="W3sZnblblabla" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWjwEC7blblabla" />
</div>
<div id="ctl00_pnlLoginBox">
<span id="ctl00_Label1">Username:</span><br />
<input name="ctl00$txtLoginName" type="text" id="ctl00_txtLoginName" style="width:100px;" /><br />
<span id="ctl00_Label2">Password:</span><br />
<input name="ctl00$txtPassword" type="password" id="ctl00_txtPassword" style="width:100px;" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$btnLogin" value="Login" id="ctl00_btnLogin" style="width:104px;" />
</div>
<div align="center" style="padding-top:2px">
<a href="/getpassword.aspx" id="ctl00_aForgotPassword">
<span>Forgot your Password</span>
</a>
</div>
```

I get the following errors:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: viewstate in /home/me/test3.php on line 101
Notice: Undefined variable: eventval in /home/me/test3.php on line 102
```

I tried set manually viewstate and eventval but it doesnt login. I tried a lot of different scripts that i found in this website but none worked. Can someone help me a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could be many reasons, i'll cover a couple (hard to say without testing this on the actual url)

**Idea 1: Incorrect Array Pointer:**
It looks like your `regexExtract()` function is not assigning a value to the `$viewstate` var - this could be because your calling `regexExtract()` with `$nthValue` as `1` - this would imply that when the `$regs` array is populated by `preg_match()` you are extracting the 2nd item in the array (dont forget php array pointers are 0 based.)

**Idea 2: Logic problem in regular expressions**
Your regular expressions are not matching any content due to a logic error - again, i cant help with this unless we can see the content being returned from `curl_exec()` - those regular expressions are designed for sites using asp.net native authentication system - are you definitly logging into an asp.net site?

Also, please remove the asp-classic tag from your question, i dont think it applies?

**EDIT:** ok, i have done some testing & got the `$viewstate` and `$eventval` vars to populate & prove the regular expressions are working OK, (and to check "1" is the correct pointer). My testing proves that the curl is correctly extracting the viewstate and posting it to the login page.

I tested this by creating the following php file (echopost.php):

```
<?
foreach($_GET as $name => $value) {
    print "QueryString: $name : $value<br>";
}
foreach($_POST as $name => $value) {
    print "POST: $name : $value<br>";
}
$cookie=$_COOKIE;
foreach ($cookie as $name=>$value) {
    print "Cookie: $name : $value<br>";
}
?>
```

I then changed this line 99~ to submit the login information to echopost & output the results (to prove that the regular expressions had correctly populated `$viewstate` and `$eventval`:

line 99~

```
curl_setOpt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.heavencore.co.uk/so/echopost.php"); //#### Note this line that changes 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFile);     

$data = curl_exec($ch); 
echo "Response from echopost.php (login): <hr />" . $data;
```

as you can see, the echopage is returning to curl the correct values from the regular expressions meaning that $viewstateand $eventval are now populated and working.

Demo: http://www.heavencore.co.uk/so/login.php
based on the dummy login page http://www.heavencore.co.uk/so/login.htm

I Changed this line:

```
function regexExtract($text, $regex, $regs, $nthValue)
```

to this:

```
function regexExtract($text, $regex, $nthValue)
```

& Changed these lines:

```
$viewstate = regexExtract($data,$regexViewstate,$regs,1); 
$eventval = regexExtract($data,$regexEventVal,$regs,1);
```

to this:

```
$viewstate = regexExtract($data,$regexViewstate,1); 
$eventval = regexExtract($data,$regexEventVal,1);
```

**EDIT 2:**

OK, This is working fine:

http://www.heavencore.co.uk/so/login.php

Note that login.php outputs the "Welcome to /../, HeavenCore!" page - meaning curl logged in OK.

My Source:

```php
<?php 
/************************************************ 
* ASP.NET web site scraping script; 
* Developed by MishaInTheCloud.com 
* Copyright 2009 MishaInTheCloud.com. All rights reserved. 
* The use of this script is governed by the CodeProject Open License 
* See the following link for full details on use and restrictions. 
*   http://www.codeproject.com/info/cpol10.aspx 
* 
* The above copyright notice must be included in any reproductions of 
this script. 
************************************************/ 
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
/************************************************ 
* values used throughout the script 
************************************************/ 
// urls to call - the login page and the secured page 
$urlLogin = "http://www.website.com/Default.aspx"; 
$urlSecuredPage = "http://www.website.com/Default.aspx"; 

// POST names and values to support login 
$nameUsername=rawurlencode('ctl00$txtLoginName');       // the name of the username textbox on the login form 
$namePassword=rawurlencode('ctl00$txtPassword');       // the name of the password textbox on the login form 
$nameLoginBtn=rawurlencode('ctl00$btnLogin');          // the name of the login button (submit) on the login form 
$valUsername ='HeavenCore';        // the value to submit for the username 
$valPassword ='password';        // the value to submit for the password 
$valLoginBtn ='Login';             // the text value of the login button itself 

// the path to a file we can read/write; this will 
// store cookies we need for accessing secured pages 
$cookieFile = 'cookie.txt'; 

// regular expressions to parse out the special ASP.NET 
// values for __VIEWSTATE and __EVENTVALIDATION 
$regexViewstate = "/__VIEWSTATE\" value=\"(.*)\"/i"; 
$regexEventVal  = "/__EVENTVALIDATION\" value=\"(.*)\"/i"; 

/************************************************ 
* utility function: regexExtract 
*    use the given regular expression to extract 
*    a value from the given text;  $regs will 
*    be set to an array of all group values 
*    (assuming a match) and the nthValue item 
*    from the array is returned as a string 
************************************************/ 
function regexExtract($text, $regex, $nthValue) 
{ 

if (preg_match($regex, $text, $regs)) { 
 $result = $regs[$nthValue]; 
} 
else { 
 $result = ""; 
} 
return $result; 
} 


/************************************************ 
* initialize a curl handle; we'll use this 
*   handle throughout the script 
************************************************/ 
$ch = curl_init(); 


/************************************************ 
* first, issue a GET call to the ASP.NET login 
*   page.  This is necessary to retrieve the 
*   __VIEWSTATE and __EVENTVALIDATION values 
*   that the server issues 
************************************************/ 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlLogin); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0' ); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
$data=curl_exec($ch); 
echo curl_error($ch); 
// from the returned html, parse out the __VIEWSTATE and 
// __EVENTVALIDATION values 
$viewstate = regexExtract($data,$regexViewstate,1); 
$eventval = regexExtract($data,$regexEventVal,1); 
/************************************************ 
* now issue a second call to the Login page; 
*   this time, it will be a POST; we'll send back 
*   as post data the __VIEWSTATE and __EVENTVALIDATION 
*   values the server previously sent us, as well as the 
*   username/password.  We'll also set up a cookie 
*   jar to retrieve the authentication cookie that 
*   the server will generate and send us upon login. 
************************************************/ 
$postData = '__VIEWSTATE='.rawurlencode($viewstate) 
          .'&__EVENTVALIDATION='.rawurlencode($eventval) 
          .'&'.$nameUsername.'='.$valUsername 
          .'&'.$namePassword.'='.$valPassword 
          .'&'.$nameLoginBtn.'='.$valLoginBtn 
          ; 

curl_setOpt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlLogin);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFile);     

$data = curl_exec($ch); 
 echo "Response from echopost.php (login): <hr />" . $data; 

/************************************************ 
* with the authentication cookie in the jar, 
* we'll now issue a GET to the secured page; 
* we set curl's COOKIEFILE option to the same 
* file we used for the jar before to ensure the 
* authentication cookie is sent back to the 
* server 
************************************************/ 
curl_setOpt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, FALSE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlSecuredPage);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieFile);     

$data = curl_exec($ch); 

// at this point the secured page may be parsed for 
// values, or additional POSTS made to submit parameters 
// and retrieve data.  For this sample, we'll just 
// echo the results. 



/************************************************ 
* that's it! Close the curl handle 
************************************************/ 
curl_close($ch); 
?>
```

Comment: Hello for your answer! I updated my question with the html code of the website. I wish that will help you!

Comment: Have you tried calling regexExtract() with $nthValue as 0 instead of 1?

Comment: i changed both `$viewstate = regexExtract($data,$regexViewstate,$regs,0);` and i get the same error:/

Comment: Is the cookie.txt file writable by php? (CHMOD 777)

Comment: I have updated my answer with some tweaks based on my testing - seems to work OK on my test box

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time mate. Yes i get no error now but my script cant login. I echo $eventval and $viewstate successfully but i think we have more errors :(

Comment: Must be a cookie problem now then, the curl cookie jar is terrible (i.e. http://hasin.me/2007/04/18/cookiejar-in-curl-it-sucks/) is the cookie file being created & populated?

Comment: Yes it gets populated and looks like this `# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curlm.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

#HttpOnly_www.website.com FALSE / FALSE 0 ASP.NET_SessionId j4uasdfsadfqf5u
#HttpOnly_www.website.com FALSE / FALSE 1336673353 .ASPXAUTH2 5135CE920sadasdas4`

Comment: Thank you very much for your time! EDIT 2 is working fine! Yahoooooo!